# Kotlin substring until specific character

Tags: string, kotlin, substring

I have a string that starts with 7 characters (let's say XXXXXXX) and after that there are 8 characters that represnet a decimal number.
For example: XXXXXXX30.00000 would be 30.00 (I want 2 decimal places)
So it should start on index 7 read until dot (.) + 2 decimal places. It should be a string, not a number. I tried with string.substring() but got stuck here.

Comment: If you know your string will always be in that format. `string.subSequence(7, string.indexOf('.') + 3)`

Comment: Does the indexOf always refer to the first found element?

Comment: Have added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can remove the first 7 characters by

```
var newString = yourString.removeRange(0,6)
```

then you can cast to a double if you're certain it will always be a number

```
var yourNumber = newString.ToDouble()
```

If you're not sure you can wrap in a try/catch eg:

```
    try{
        var yourNumber = newString.ToDouble()
    }catch(e:TypeCastException){
       println("Failed to cast to double - "+ e.message)
    }
```

additionally, to round to a 2 decimal places:

```
val number2digits:Double = String.format("%.2f", yourNumber).toDouble()
```

Comment: It rounds it, but doesn't return two zeroes: 30.0 instead of 30.00

Comment: Remember that [floating-point numbers are not precise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken/588014).  (Or rather, they're precise for binary fractions, but not for decimal fractions as in this question.)  If you need precision, consider storing as a [BigDecimal](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/java.math.-big-decimal/), a scaled integer, or even a String.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do it using the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Kwq2CM/1), `[A-Za-z]{8}(\d+.\d{2})`

**Explanation of the regex:**

1. `[A-Za-z]{8}` specifies 8 characters. If you want to support characters other than `English` alphabets, you can replace `[A-Za-z]` with `\p{L}` which specifies [unicode letters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).
2. `(\d+.\d{2})` specifies a [capturing group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) consisting of digits followed by `.` which in turn should be followed by `2` digits as per your requirement. A regex pattern can have more than one capturing groups. Since it is the first capturing group in this pattern, it can be accessed by `group(1)`.

**A test code:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Some test strings
        String[] arr = { "abcdefgh30.00000", "abcdefgh300.0000", "abcdefgh3000.00", "abcdefgh3.00000",
                "abcdefgh0.05000" };
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]{8}(\\d+.\\d{2})");
        for (String s : arr) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                String str = matcher.group(1);
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
30.00
300.00
3000.00
3.00
0.05
```